# SCP destination path with drive

Tags: scp

I want to copy a file to another server using the following command.

```
scp source_file_name username@destination_host:destination_folder
```

In my case, my destination folder is in a different drive. So, I need to pass the drive in path also. I tried using `f:` in the path of the destination folder. But it is not able to copy to the desired location.

I tried to pass the path along with the drive but I am not able to see the file getting copied there. I am getting the understanding that I will be able to write only inside the directory mapped.

Please note it is a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the drive letter after a slash followed by a slash, it's treated as a directory.

Like this:
`scp source_file_name username@destination_host:/f/destination_folder`

Comment: this does not work for me, claiming no such file or directory

Comment: You probably do not have such directory then...

Comment: i have the drive letter i specified. but after playing around with it more, it seems that depending on how the drive letter was mounted, it may be necessary to specify it differently